# Vector of pointer to functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I want to create a vector of pointer to functions. The function itself is just one but it can take different parameters. What I would like is when I push them into the vector can pass arguments to the function.

For instance, this is the function:

```
bool myFunction(char* fmt ...) { 
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);

    while (*fmt != '\0') {
        if (*fmt == 'f') {
            double f = va_arg(args, double);
            printf("F: %f\n",f);
        } else if (*fmt == 's') {
            char * s = va_arg(args, char*);
            std::cout << s << '\n';
        }
        ++fmt;
    }

    va_end(args);

    return true;
} 

typedef bool(*myFuncPtr)(char* fmt ...);
std::vector<myFuncPtr> functions;
std::vector<myFuncPtr>::iterator it;

int main(int argc, char* argc[])
{
   functions.push_back(&myFunction);
   functions.push_back(&myFunction);
   it = functions.begin();

   bResult = (*it)("f", 1.0f);
   it++;
   bResult = (*it)("f", 2.0f);
   it++;

return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but I would prefer to do something like this:

functions.push_back(myFunction("f",1.0f));

it = functions.begin();

bResult = (*it);

But it doesn't work in this way. Can someone help me to manage it? I wouldn't like to go through the vector manually as described in the first case.

Comment: What about using `std::function<>`? Also what you wan seems to defeat the purpose od function pointers, why would you want to store the conrete parameter values along with the function?

Comment: You want to store the function pointers with their own intput parameters? (doesn't sound posible) or just calling them?

Comment: How would it be? Can it be possible?

Comment: @user3593264 _"Can it be possible?"_ Somehow yes, wrapping everything into a dispatcher class or such, but what do you actually want? So far this looks like an xy problem for me.

Comment: I would like to store the functions pointers with their own input parameters and then,  I would like to go through the vector with an iterator to calling each function. Is it possible?

Comment: More possible than `int main(int argc, char* argc[])`, which isn't even valid C. Regardless, binding arguments to a callable is certainly doable (in fact, there are several ways to do it, but I'm not convinced it will solve the *real* problem, whatever it is).

Comment: @user3593264 Additional requirements and information [go to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68113388/edit) please.

Answer (score 3):

You need type-erasing for that. C++11 has `std::function` which does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int func(char const* p) {
  printf("%s ", p);
  return strlen(p);
}

int main() {
  using Callback = std::function<int(void)>;
  std::vector<Callback> functions;
  functions.emplace_back([] { return func("Hello"); });
  functions.emplace_back([] { return func("World"); });

  for (auto const& f : functions) {
    printf("%d\n", f());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. It is working properly

Comment: @user3593264 glad I could help! Have a look at [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Is it possible to do the same in other way with c++ standard previous to c++11?

Comment: @user3593264 Sure. See [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9e5T5hWW9). Also see `std::bind1st`, `std::bind2nd`. Additionally, Boost.Function may have been available pre-c++11.